# I need to record some datas in user params when submit login

Tags: user, component-params

I have a login page and I need to perform some styles for users choice.
Then, when user select some preset style, the website changes the style.
I need to do it recording as some user params or in another component or table.

Comment: This sounds like a request for free work to be done or a third-party product to be recommended. (This normally gets smacked down on StackOverflow, but Joomla Stack Exchange is a bit gentler/welcoming in its dealings.) Please post what you have tried, what research you've done, what pages are similar on JSE, and try to narrow down the support that you require. Do you have any working parts implemented in your project? Please specify more details and make your question easier to answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you can do to accomplish what you want:

- Override the login page to include the additional fields (such as the styles, etc...)
- Create a different login plugin (just copy the authentication/joomla plugin) and use that plugin instead of the default one. In the `onUserAuthenticate` function of that plugin, just add the code to store the additional fields in the database when the authentication is successful. You can also store this information in the session in order to prevent querying the database for the custom user settings on each page load.